# Jittering when moving player

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, game-physics, game-development

I have a project where I combine 2D and 3D elements. The project itself is 3D and when I try to move my player it jitters. I tried using fixedDeltaTime and tried to useLateUpdate but none of them worked. I don't know what I did wrong. It was working fine at first but when I added the camera script and played with colliders it became like this.

```
using UnityEngine;

public class CameraController : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private Transform target;
    [SerializeField] private float smoothSpeed  = 0.125f;
    [SerializeField] private Vector3 offset;
    private Vector3 zero = Vector3.zero;

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        Vector3 desiredPosition = target.position + offset;
        Vector3 smoothedPosition = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, desiredPosition, smoothSpeed);
        transform.position = smoothedPosition;

        transform.LookAt(target);
    }
}
```

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Rigidbody rb;
    private Animator anim;
    [SerializeField] private float hDirection;
    [SerializeField] private float vDirection;

    [SerializeField] private Collider coll;
    [SerializeField] private float hSpeed = 0.5f;
    [SerializeField] private float vSpeed = 0.5f;

    private enum State { idle, running, turnRight, turnLeft};
    State state = State.idle;

    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        Move();
    }


    private void Move()
    {
        hDirection = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        vDirection = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

        if (hDirection > 0)
        {
            transform.position += transform.right * Time.fixedDeltaTime * hSpeed;
        }
        if (hDirection < 0)
        {
            transform.position -= transform.right * Time.fixedDeltaTime * hSpeed;
        }
        if (vDirection > 0)
        {
            transform.position += transform.forward * Time.fixedDeltaTime * vSpeed;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using a physical body (Rididbody) for your player, but you are moving it with `transform.position`. This is not the correct way. You either need to control your `rb` with [MovePosition()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.MovePosition.html), or change the velocity of it. Or you can use CharacterController and its methods for movement.

Just remember - don't use `transform` for physical movement.

**EDIT:** also, remember that movements I've described above must be inside `FixedUpdate()`, not just `Update()`.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the camera script for you, Vector3.Lerp() takes two points and a decimal between 0-1, this decimal represents a position between the two endpoints. The left endpoint is 0 and the right endpoint is 1. 0.5 returns the endpoint between the two points. Bring the rigTransform closer to the target position in a gradual and slow manner. That is - the camera will follow the player character. Back to Unity. Select Main Camera in the structure view, in the inspector, the Target is Player

```
   using UnityEngine;
   using System.Collections;
   public class CameraController : MonoBehaviour
  {
   [SerializeField] private Transform rigTransform;
   [SerializeField] public GameObject target;
   [SerializeField] public float smoothSpeed  = 0.125f;


   void Start(){
    target = this.transform.parent;
    }

  void FixedUpdate()
   {
    if(target == null){
        return;
    }
  
    rigTransform.position = Vector3.Lerp(rigTransform.position, 
    target.transform.position, 
    Time.deltaTime * smoothSpeed);
  }
}
```